# Looking for a Fantasy book thats starts with a boy who has to build a home from a log that once was a person

Tags: story-identification

I think I have read this book in the nineties, and I just remember some bits of it. Tried to google it several times, but sadly could not find it. I am sorry if it does not make any sense, and for my spelling mistakes. English is not my first language.

- I think it starts with a boy entering an other world, but I do not remember how he got there. I believe he wants to become a wizard or mage.
- Then he has to build a simple home, or hut in the middle of the night (I think). he has to finish before dawn and he has to use a log (and all of the log). At first he does not know how to start since he has no tools, but then he finds a place where he has to push and the log says something and turns into some wooden planks. In the end he has build the home and is left with just a small peace of wood.
- The only other thing I remember that in the end (spoiler) he becomes a wizard and creates different worlds (from pearls from his hands?) and that our 'real' world collides with one of them.
- Oh and something with wine tasting to enter other worlds. And fruit growing on trees that taste like meat (wish that was existed)

I am so sorry I do not remember anything more, but I really hope somebody out there knows what I am talking about. I know I liked the book, and I would really love to read it again.

Comment: What language did you read it in (from your name I'm guessing Nederlands) and do you think it was a translation from another language or not?

Comment: Sounds a bit like MineCraft ))

Comment: @bob1 I think I read it in Dutch, but since Alith answered the question (yeah!) it was clearly a translation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is 2 books by Greg Bear [*The Infinity Concerto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinity_Concerto) and it's sequel [*The Serpent Mage*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpent_Mage_(Greg_Bear)).  The Infinity Concerto was first published in 1984 so fits in your timeframe of reading these in the early 90's.

The boy is Michael Perrin and his is chosen by a composer to be his executor after the composer (Arno Waltiri) dies.

> In 1939, a composer named Arno Waltiri premiered his latest work, Concerto Opus 45: "Infinity". After the concert, another composer, who had been in the audience, filed a lawsuit against Waltiri, claiming that he was no longer able to properly hear or compose music after hearing Waltiri's work. Over the next several months, dozens of people simply disappeared, and the only thing they had in common with one another was that they had been in the audience at that same performance. Waltiri had been inspired to write the concerto by several conversations with a mysterious man named David Clarkham. The Concerto turns out to have been a "Song of Power", Songs of Power, if properly applied by those who understand them, have the power to literally remake the world. Songs of Power can exist in many artistic forms, including music, poetry, dance, art, architecture, and some less obvious creative fields. Clarkham had disappeared after the performance too, but he had left Waltiri a book and the key to his house, which Waltiri had never used.

> The book's present story follows the experiences of a young man named Michael Perrin, a would be poet, who meets Waltiri two months before his death, and to whom Waltiri gives the book and the key. Following the instructions on a piece of paper he found inserted in the book, Perrin enters Clarkham's house, which has been vacant for decades, and soon finds himself in Sidhedark, a world inhabited by a powerful race of beings calling themselves the Sidhe (pronounced "shee"). He appears at what he learns is the house of someone called the "Isomage", who disappeared years ago, and meets a huge, strange woman named Lamia, who lives there. Michael is already in danger, because by treaty there is only one town where humans are safe from being hunted and killed by the Sidhe: Euterpe, where Lamia hastily sends Michael before anyone finds him.

The house building scene happens to Michael when he is being trained to survive in Sidhedark, by a group of 3 half breeds, named the Crane Women.  He has only a night to build the house/hut and finds that pressing in various places on the wood causes it to become logs, shingles etc.

In the end Michael meets Clarkham and discovers that he himself has the power to create worlds, via the nacre substance that comes from his hands.  This is covered more fully in the second book when Michael enters a battle to create a world under the urging of the Serpent Mage, which is where Michael creates a way for Earth and Sidhedark to merge allowing the Sidhe to return to live among humans.

The memory of tasting wine acting as a way to enter worlds is also in the second book where Michael has to rescue his love interest from a world created by a "shadow" of Clarkham.

[image: The Infinity Concerto cover]

Comment: I find myself still a bit baffled about the "log that used to be a person" part.

Comment: IIRC @fuzzyboots, the Sidhe when they die could opt to have their soul impressed into a tree, the logs cut from those trees retained a semblance of the Sidhe's personality and could communicate..

Comment: @Alith Oh yes, it all comes back now! And the log (or the soul of the deseased Sidhe) was quite annoyed that the wood was used by a mere human. I'm ordering the books right away :D